# Best Architecture for a Public Queue of Incoming Requests?

Tags: architecture, system-design

We have a web app (ASP) that has workflow in it for management to assign work to individuals. The problem is prior to signing out work.  During the evening/night/early morning operations are lightly staffed so the management queue of work may not be watched closely if other critical work is being performed away from the computer (getting tools from shelves for mechanics). So we have a functional requirement to create a program to a continually refreshing display of new unassigned work on a monitor or TV screen in the work area.

My question:  Is there any recommended best practices for the deployment architecture?  Web vs Desktop Thick Client application?

**Web:**

Pro - Keeps the architecture consistent

Cons - Control of box may difficult we have take extra steps to ensure the box is not hi-jacked to other sites, controlling limited logins, other security and computer  resource

**Desktop Thick Client:**

Cons - Both Web and Clients apps now need to be supported. Will require two instances deployed to two locations

Pros - Security and limiting use of box are simple.  No app security log in required so functions like PE can bring app back up if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created something similar in the past. I used a "Jack PC" (http://www.chippc.com/thin-clients/jack-pc/index.asp) with a large LCD TV connected to it. The Jack PC was configured to automatically connect to server using RDP and scripted to start up a Windows Forms application on the server. The Windows Forms application was basically a form with a WebBrowser control. This application basically called a query according to a pre-defined schedule looking for URL's to load. There was a second Web application that contained pages with the logic to load / display the data. Essentially it could display any HTML content, reports included. Hope this gives you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like a scenario suited to the [Observer Pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) This will allow you to roll future 'observers' (mobile devices, desktops etc) without the need to re-architect your core workflow application.